Configure Hibernate to dynamic partitioning of mysql table
Let's consider this table:
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int DEFAULT 2000
)

I would love to get my_table (and two other tables) partitioned based on the value of year (yearis Superior to 2000) and get all CRUD statements possible from my Application using hibernate.
for the moment all I have are manually  defined tables my_table_2000,my_table_2001,...
and for each I have an Entity:
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyTable_2000 {
    @Id
    String id;
    Integer year;
}

a repository for each one, and, in each year, I need to create new partitions and update the code which is complicated.
since MySql supports only list and range partitioning, I am asking if hibernate can help with  partitioning management specially to auto create partitions each time we try to save an entity with a new value of year
I work in spring boot ecosystem

Which MySQL Version? Also YEAR is its own datatype in MySQL. You're probably also seen the requirement that year has to be part of the primary key. What purpose are you doing partitioning? Is there a expiry dropping partition at some point or is there another goal being achieved? Have you verified the goal is achieved via partitioning?
